# Laravel backpack form request getting empty input

Tags: laravel-backpack

Laravel backpack auto generated form request for crud. How should i get the input from the form request to use it in unique validation eg: email?

I've tried dd($this), but all the value is empty or null. i think the request is not passing in at all ?

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email', $this->id
    ];
}
```

I expect to get the id from the request and using it in my unique form validation

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how you are able to get the ID from the form. And it's working in an official Backpack package - https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager/blob/master/src/app/Http/Requests/UserUpdateCrudRequest.php . It's possible you're missing something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the id with the below simple way , i have tried it and it works for me.

```
public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->get('id') ?? request()->route('id');
    return [
        'email' => 'required|unique:users,email', $id
    ];
}
```

Referenced from the below mentioned url

https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager/blob/master/src/app/Http/Requests/UserUpdateCrudRequest.php

Answer (score 1):

If you dd($this) you will get nothing because the method rules() is called on page load and not only on form submission. If you want to check the submitted values, you can use something like:

```
if (!$this->id) dd($this);
```

Then, under request->parameters, you can see the value of all the fields included in the request.